# Sum() returns incorrect value when joining multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sum

I have four tables:

Table orders:

```
o_id    o_c_id  o_type      o_date
1       23    TA          2015-01-01
2       24    TA          2015-01-16
3       25    GA          2015-01-08
4       26    TA          2016-01-24
5       26    FB          2016-01-28
```

Table customers:

```
c_id    c_name  c_email
23       Ander   xxx@gmail.com          
24       Kay     xxx@gmail.com
25       Bob     xxx@gmail.com
26       Devi    xxx@gmail.com
```

Table services:

```
s_o_id    s_name  s_nr  s_amount
1       SGHH   75454645   350     
1       SGHH   75454645   420
2       TAK    74322411   214
3       BGH    74288442   850
```

Table external:

```
ext_id ext_name ext_nr  ext_amount
1      Gerry   75454645   350
1      Gerry   75454645   420
2      Alby    74322411   214
3      Alby    74288442   850
```

The result should look like this :

```
| c_name   | o_date        | ext_name |  ext_nr  |   s_nr    | ext_amount | s_amount |
|----------|---------------|----------|----------|-----------|------------|----------|
| Ander    | 2016-09-19    | Gerry    | 75454645 | 75454645  |   760      |  730     |
```

My query:

```
SELECT c.c_name
     , o.o_date 
     , s.s_name
     , ext.ext_nr
     , s.s_nr
     , SUM(ext.ext_amount) 
     , SUM(s.s_amount) 
  FROM orders o
  JOIN customer c 
    ON o.c_id = c.c_id
  JOIN services s 
    ON s.o_id = o.o_id
 RIGHT 
  JOIN external ext 
    ON ext.ext_nr = s.s_nr
 GROUP 
    BY s.s_nr;
```

The sum of the amounts for the different nr's returned are incorrect, i assume it is because of the joins.

Comment: I cannot find `s.o_id`, your example seems wrong to me. You should probably create a test case, i.e. remove everything which is not contributing to your problem and make it as easy as possible to understand what is going on.

Comment: Why grouping only by `s.s_nr`? Why ot all the cols. Put all the cols in Group By clause except aggregated columns.

Comment: I get the same result ..

Answer (score 0):

You should use `JOIN` (which defaults to INNER JOIN) all through, and add all the columns in the group by clause excep the aggregated columns:

```
SELECT c.c_name
 , o.o_date 
 , s.s_name
 , ext.ext_nr
 , s.s_nr
 , SUM(ext.ext_amount) 
 , SUM(s.s_amount) 
FROM orders o
JOIN customer c 
ON o.c_id = c.c_id
JOIN services s 
ON s.o_id = o.o_id
JOIN external ext 
ON ext.ext_nr = s.s_nr
GROUP BY
   c.c_name
 , o.o_date 
 , s.s_name
 , ext.ext_nr
 , s.s_nr;
```

For more understanding on using joins in sql [click here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx)

Comment: i tried it with a inner join instead of a right join and grouped it as you suggested but the result set did not change

Answer (score 0):

The join between external and services have 2 rows with links to the same shared value, 75454645.  This will will produce additional rows in the result set (6 rows total out of 4, I think).